# Reset form with original state

Tags: vb.net, winforms, reset

I would like to reset my form using vb.net i would try to below code but form is close can't open new form.

```
Private Sub resert_button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles resert_button.Click
        Dim client = New client_entry
        client.Show()
        Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: I assume `client_entry` is the name of your first form or the form you are trying to open. Try changing `Dim client_entry = New client_entry` and `client_entry.Show()` to `Dim client = New client_entry` and `client.Show()`.

Comment: @ArunKumar thanks for help but it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Try `Me.Hide` and swap the order

```
Me.Hide()
client.Show()
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple ways to handle this one but myapproach would be like calling form_shown even where I will load required data and during reset i will call this event.

```
Private Sub Me_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
   LoadData() 'This function/sub will load data for this form
End Sub

Private Sub resert_button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles resert_button.Click
        Me_Shown(sender,e) 
End Sub
```

Comment: That would be your function/sub you load data when form loads

Answer (score 0):

Use Me.Dispose() instead of Me.Close() it will dispose the form then when you call it again Yourform.Show(), It will Generate a new one.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this would be to add a property to Form2. I'm assuming that you have two forms Lets call them Form1 and Form2. Somewhere in the code for Form1, you declare an instance of Form2 ..

```
Dim frm2 As New Form2
```

and at some point you want to show Form2 as a modal window ..

```
frm2.ShowDialog()
```

For the moment lets look at the Form2 code

I'm assuming here that you have a button to reset the form and to close the form, you just click on the form close button in the top right hand corner and maybe you have a button to close the form as well. Consider the following code for Form2

```
Public Class Form2

    Friend Property resetOnClose As Boolean = False

    Private Sub btnReset_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnReset.Click
        resetOnClose = True
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnclose_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnclose.Click
        resetOnClose = False
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub
End Class
```

There is a property called `resetOnclose` which is a Boolean type. If you click on the reset button, this property is set to `True` If you click on the close button, the `resetOnClose` property is set to false.

In all these bits of code, `frm2` is Hidden - not closed. This means that the form and its `resetOnclose` property is still available to Form1. OK now to look at the Form1 code ..

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim frm2 As New Form2

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
        frm2.ShowDialog()
        Do
            If frm2.resetOnClose Then
                frm2.Close()
                frm2 = New Form2
                frm2.ShowDialog()
            Else
                frm2.Close()
            End If
        Loop Until frm2.resetOnClose = False
    End Sub
End Class
```

For this example, `frm2` is opened as soon as Form1 is shown, but you can put the relevant code anywhere you need

In the `Form1.Shown` code you will see a loop. The loop will continue looping as long as `resetOnClose` is `True`. When `frm1` is shown modally, execution in this Form1 code waits until `frm2` is hidden or closed. Next, the Form1 code checks to see if the `resetOnClose` property is true or false. If it's false, `frm2` is closed and the loop terminates. If the property is true, `frm2` is closed and reassigned a new instance of `Form2` in its default state.

Voila!